# How do I delete a Git branch that has no name

Tags: git, git-rebase

I'm not sure exactly how this happened. But after a rebase I have a no-name detached branch that is a partial duplicate of the master. I probably made some error in rebasing from a branch of a branch. So basically how do I delete the branch whose tip is 0ac0e6b?

```
* 11e604e (HEAD -> master) Some comment
* a50932a Another comment
....
....
* 0d85332 Activities: service <-- dupes below
* 5323616 Activities: setup   <-- 
* e4f5063 Results: fix        <--
* 5bf3ec0 Composer: update
| * 0ac0e6b XController Setup (tag: sometag)   <-- THIS BRANCH HAS NO NAME
| * a34b800
| * dccbd3b 
| * 020b15e Activities: service   <-- dupes above
| * f4231cf Activities: setup     <--
| * 118536f Results: fix          <--
|/  
* c42ad6f Some comment
```

[Turns out the issue was a tag in the branch seemingly preventing it from being deleted - I'll leave this here in case someone comes across the same issue. Delete the tag, and the branch in my case disappeared. Added the tag in an edit.]

Comment: Do you mean a detached head, a branch with an empty string as a name, or something else?

Comment: I'm not sure the correct term. But you can see the in the output above. The branch on the right ( c42ad6f ~ 0ac0e6b) has no name. That's the one I want to delete.

Comment: @Gazzer I could not see any duplicate! Are you sure you have it somewhere else?

Comment: @Gazzer There is just one `XController Setup`

Comment: Actually I managed to solve the issue myself. The duplicates were the three other ones 'Results: fix` etc. , not the `XController Setup`.
I'm still wondering how the whole thing happened though!

Comment: @Gazzer `-D` option for `git branch` just removes the branch name. commit will be remains!

Comment: Yes, you are correct. See my comment below. Deleting the tags turned out to be the solution, so the question was not very well phrased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you discovered, for Git to *find* a commit in the first place, it must be looking at *some* name for the commit.  In this case, that was a tag name.

The most curious part is this `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph` output, which I will snip down to just two critical lines (and one "..."):

> ```
> * 11e604e (HEAD -> master) Some comment
> ...
> | * 0ac0e6b XController Setup
> ```

The first one shows us that you're using `--decorate`: the commit is shown with the name(s) by which Git *found* that commit in parentheses.

Then we get to the mystery commit.  Since you are using `--decorate`, this *should* read:

```
| * 0ac0e6b (tag: sometag) XController Setup
```

which would tell us that the tag `sometag` is the name by which Git found this newly introduced stream of commits.

Once Git has found any particular commit, of course, it uses that commit's parent hash ID to find the commit's parent, so:

```
| * a34b800
| * dccbd3b
```

and so on are no mystery: they're found via the hash ID—the "true name", as it were—of commit `0ac0e6b`.  In particular, `a34b800` is `0ac0e6b`'s parent, `dccbd3b` is `a34b800`'s parent, and so on.

#### This is actually a key insight into Git

It's worth thinking about this: a branch name, in Git, doesn't *create* the commits.  It just lets Git *find* the commits, and it does this by pointing directly to one—just **one**—commit.  Git calls this pointed-to commit the *tip* of the branch.

In order to add new commits to an existing branch, what Git does is:

- Write out a new commit, with its source snapshot, author name, and all the other usual metadata you see in `git log`.  One of these bits of metadata is the commit's *parent ID* hash.

  The parent ID of the new commit is the commit to which the branch name points:

  ```
  ... <--commit <--commit <--current-tip-commit   <-- branchname
                                   \
                             new-commit-just-made
  ```
- And, now that the *new* commit exists, *change* the stored hash in the branch name.  The branch name no longer points to the previous tip commit.  Now it points to the new commit you just made!

  ```
  ... <--commit <--commit <--current-tip-commit
                                   \
                             new-commit-just-made   <-- branchname
  ```

When Git does all this fancy moving-about of the branch name, *only one name actually moves*.  That's the branch that `git status` says that you are "on", as in `git status` saying `on branch master`.  *All other existing names are undisturbed*.  If any of those point to the current commit, they continue to point to the current commit.

This is what most commonly goes wrong with `git rebase`, which works by *copying* commits—some string of commits computed by the arguments you pass to `git rebase`—to shiny new commits that (we hope anyway) are an improvement over the old dull ones.  Then it moves the one branch name.  As long as that one branch name was the *only* way to find the old commits, now Git only has a way to find the *new* commits, and it looks like the commits have changed—but they haven't!  The old ones are still in there.

As soon as we have a second name—branch name, tag name, `refs/stash` reference, remote-tracking name, or whatever new thing you invent for some reason—through which Git finds the *old* commits, though, well, there they are in `git log --all`.  And now you have to find some way to get *those* names to move; and if they are tag names, moving them is usually a bad idea.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the detailed writeup. I actually removed the tag because I erroneously thought it was irrelevant to the question thus removing the vital piece of the puzzle!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to clean the repository you can use `git gc` [command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc). `gc` stands for garbage collector which removes unnecessary(i.e commits which have not belongs to any branch) commits.

Comment: I think the issue here turned out to be something else. It seems that the branch wasn't deleted automatically because it contained tags.
I'm still at a loss to explain why this (almost) duplicate branch appeared.

Comment: @Gazzer I could not find any option for `rebase` to save the original branch. Also as a nasty solution you can remove tags from that branch and use `gc` to remove it, if it has useless commits.